# Nested procedures with transactions

Tags: stored-procedures, transactions, sql-server-2000

I have the following problem. I have to stored procedures (debug messages double-indended):

```
CREATE PROC innerProc
AS 
BEGIN
        SELECT 'innerProc 1',@@TRANCOUNT
    BEGIN TRAN
        SELECT 'innerProc 2',@@TRANCOUNT
    ROLLBACK
        SELECT 'innerProc 3',@@TRANCOUNT
END

GO  -----------------------------------------

CREATE PROC outerProc
AS 
BEGIN
        SELECT 'outerProc 1',@@TRANCOUNT
    BEGIN TRAN
        SELECT 'outerProc 2',@@TRANCOUNT
    EXEC innerProc
        SELECT 'outerProc 3',@@TRANCOUNT
    ROLLBACK
        SELECT 'outerProc 4',@@TRANCOUNT
END

GO  -----------------------------------------

EXEC outerProc
```

What they do?

1. `outerProc` begins transaction (@@TRANCOUNT = 1)
2. executes `innerProc` (@@TRANCOUNT at the beginning of the proc = 1)
3. `innerProc` begins another transaction (@@TRANCOUNT = 2)
4. `innerProc` rollbacks transaction (@@TRANCOUNT = 0)
5. **AND HERE IS THE PROBLEM**: @@TRANCOUNT at the beginning of the `innerProc` is not equal to @@TRANCOUNT at the end. What am I doing wrong? Is it correct approach?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Nope. It didn't work with named transactions. I have read some opinions and I think transaction and procedures are not ment to work together.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use named transactions or else you're killing all transactions when you rollback on the nested one, even if it is scoped to just the inner sproc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Further reading:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx

> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION without a
>   savepoint_name or transaction_name 
>   rolls back to the beginning of the
>   transaction. When nesting
>   transactions, this same statement
>   rolls back all inner transactions to
>   the outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION
>   statement. In both cases, ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION decrements the @@TRANCOUNT
>   system function to 0. ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION savepoint_name does not
>   decrement @@TRANCOUNT.